# Android - Storing information about User on login in JSON

Tags: java, android, json, sharedpreferences

In my application, a user logs in on the `LoginActivity`, upon which a login session is created using a `SessionManager` class I created (I have a `SharedPreferences` object in it, for which I `put` the user's email in and put a boolean `isLoggedIn` to true).

Now, what I really want to do is put the User's `JSONObject` that I get from the server in the `LoginActivity` upon login, into the `SharedPreferences`. Basically I want to be able to access the `JSON` document from anywhere in the application while the user is logged in.

However, I realize I can't put a `JSONObject` into the editor. What is the correct way to implement the functionality I'm describing though?

If relevant... this is my `SessionManager` class which has a `SharedPreferences` object in it (I don't know if this is the best way to do it):

```
package com.xxx.xxxx;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.xxxx.auth.LoginActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

public class SessionManager {
   // Shared Preferences
   SharedPreferences pref;

   // Editor for Shared preferences
   Editor editor;

   // Context
   Context _context;

   // Shared pref mode
   int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

   // Sharedpref file name
   private static final String PREF_NAME = "PREFS";

   // All Shared Preferences Keys
   private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

   // Email address
   public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

   // Constructor
   public SessionManager(Context context) {
       this._context = context;
       pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
       editor = pref.edit();
   }

   /** Create login session */
   public void createLoginSession(String email){
       // Storing login value as TRUE
       editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

       // Storing email in pref
       editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);

       // I WANTED TO STORE THE JSON HERE AFTER PASSING IT AS A PARAMETER
       // IN THE METHOD

       // commit changes
       editor.commit();
   }   


   /**
    * Get stored session data
    * */
  public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
       HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

       // user email id
       user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

       // return user
       return user;
   }

   /**
    * Clear session details
    * */
   public void logoutUser(){
       // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
       editor.clear();
       editor.commit();

       redirect();
   }

   public void redirect() {
       //redirect user to Login Activity
       Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);

       // Closing all the Activities
       i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

       // Add new Flag to start new Activity
       i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

       // Staring Login Activity
       _context.startActivity(i);
   }

   // Get Login State
   public boolean isLoggedIn() {
       return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
   }
}
```

Comment: just call toString() on your jsonobject and you can store it in sharedpreferences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store only simple types in Preferences http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html. If you really want to save JSON, save it as String and parse it with GSON (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or some other JSON mapper.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the String back to the `JSON` object using the library? I'm looking at the user guide, but I can't find anything on `JSONObject`s.

Comment: Take a look at documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html.

JSONObject(String json)
Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from the JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize `JSONObject` in a file inside SD Card. `SharedPreferences` is not designed to handle it. But don't add sensitive data inside the file. If the `JSONObject` size is little, then you can try the below code. You need `Gson` library to do this.

```
public static void setJSONObject(Context context, YourObject obj){
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("YOUR_OBJECT",new Gson().toJson(obj)); 
    editor.commit();
}

public static YourObject getJSONObject (Context context){
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String stringobj = preferences.getString("YOUR_OBJECT", "");
    if(stringobj.equals(""))return null;
    else return new Gson().fromJson(stringobj, YourObject.class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use gson library (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert json object to and from String.

Usage:

```
(Serialization)
UserInfo obj = new UserInfo();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);  
==> json is {"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}
```

You can save the json string in SharedPreferences.
Later, to get back the json object do a de-serialization.

```
(Deserialization)
UserInfo user = gson.fromJson(json, UserInfo.class);   
==> user is just like obj
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use sqlite to store information.

OR

Write JSONObject in file on your phone memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to store your JSON in the SharedPreferences - SharedPreferences wasn't designed to store small amounts of data and is relatively slow to read from.

The best thing you can do is to store your JSON in a private file and read from that file. You can create and write your JSON to a private file by doing the following (taken from Android developer docs):

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String json = my_json_data.toString();

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(json.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

You can read from this file by calling `openFileInput()` and passing in `FILENAME`.

Answer (score 0):

Store the `JSONObject` as String.

Create another Key

```
public static final String KEY_JSON = "user_json";
```

Modify your `createLoginSession` method

```
public void createLoginSession(String email, JSONObject user_data){
       // Storing login value as TRUE
       editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

       // Storing email in pref
       editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);

       // I WANTED TO STORE THE JSON HERE AFTER PASSING IT AS A PARAMETER
       // IN THE METHOD
```

> ```
>      editor.putString(KEY_JSON, user_data.toString());
> ```

```
       // commit changes
       editor.commit();
   }
```

I hope that helps.